# Revision '<SERVICE_NAME>-00037-hep' does not exist or is deleted. Update all traffic to route to currently available revisions

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I was creating a past revision in Cloud Run and received the following error message.

## Error Message

Revision '<SERVICE_NAME>-00037-hep' does not exist or is deleted. Update all traffic to route to currently available revisions.

After this, I am unable to switch traffic or build a new build.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rVRd.png)

What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit same issue. I looks like there are non-existing entries in Cloud Run service traffic routing list.

You can use `gcloud run services describe <SERVICE_NAME> --format=json | jq '.status.traffic'` to see the full traffic routing list

Initially I tried to remove only broken revision using tag that was mapped to missing revision using `gcloud run services update-traffic <SERVICE_NAME> --remove-tags ...` command, but it did not work.

In the end I used following workaround:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic <SERVICE_NAME> --clear-tags
```

this removed all the tags attached to this service. Then I restored only some important tags manually.